# git log with --name-status only for certain commits?

Tags: git, git-log

This is the logging I use. `git ls` shows my branch up to and including the point of divergence from develop. `git lg` shows a graph with both my branch and develop from the point of divergence.

```
$ git config --global alias.ls '!git log --oneline --first-parent ^$(git merge-base HEAD origin/develop)~ HEAD'

$ git config --global alias.lg '!git log --oneline --first-parent --graph --topo-order ^$(git merge-base HEAD origin/develop)~ HEAD origin/develop'

$ git ls
b8e6bm5 (HEAD -> mybranch) Fix thing
38g9aaf Add thing
8sf4978 Pull request #107: Mediocre feature

$ git lg
* b8e6bm5 (HEAD -> mybranch) Fix thing
* 38g9aaf Add thing
| * 2ef614a (origin/develop, origin/HEAD, develop) Pull request #109: Cool feature
| * aa1gf3b Pull request #108: Really cool feature
|/
* 8sf4978 Pull request #107: Mediocre feature
```

I'd also like to be able to show `--name-status` for all but the last commit, or perhaps for just the non-develop commits. Can this be done?